# Rails 3 - how to defer parsing of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, deferred-execution

I am trying to optimize my website and one of the suggestions I got was to defer parsing of JavaScript. I have googled it for a couple of hours but I haven't come across an elegant solution to do this in Rails 3. I am using the standard

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :application -%>
```

tag in my code, just before . Does anybody know a relatively simple way to defer the loading of all the Javascript of the application.js file? Thanks.

Comment: @phoet He is probably refering to a website speed test, where this is a common advice. "294.4KiB of JavaScript is parsed during initial page load.Defer parsing JavaScript to reduce blocking of page rendering." 
See: http://gtmetrix.com/

Comment: You are stating that you have the tag "just before ." - which word is missing here?

Comment: <\head> is missing :) It is indeed to improve the score on a speed test. Javascript should be loaded at the end of the page load. Haven't found a solution yet, so if anyone has any ideas...

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but in case someone is still looking for a solution:
I solved the problem moving the `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` to the end.

```
  ....
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :media => 'all' %>
</head>
<body>
  ...
</body>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
</html>
```

I hope it helps someone...